# Neutrino Mass from Tritium

Tags: electrons, mass, nuclear-physics, neutrinos

I just read: [Researchers close in on the elusive neutrino (phys.org)](https://phys.org/news/2023-09-elusive-neutrino.html)

However, I think I'm missing something.  The basic argument appears to be:

(decay process)

- Tritium -> Helium-3 + β− (electron) + neutrino

```
Tritium mass: known
Helium-3 mass: known
β− (electron) mass: known
```

So neutrino mass known.

However, they're talking like it requires an experiment.  From WP:

```
Tritium: 3.01604928 Da
Helium-3: 3.0160293 Da
β− (electron): 0.0005485799 Da
```

Because mass calc can be rearranged as:

- neutrino = Tritium - ( Helium-3 + β− (electron) )

Doesn't that mean?:

Neutrino mass = 3.01604928 - ( 3.0160293 + 0.0005485799 ) = -0.0005285999 Da

There's the energy of release (18.6 keV: known) and the energy of the electron (5.7 keV avg: known), yet those are both small compared to the electron's rest energy of 511 keV.  They also just seem to result in a larger negative.

I feel like I must just be making a math error somewhere or not comprehending the issue.  What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: As per special relativity it's really not as simple as summing the masses since the particles also have momentum after the decay.

Comment: Daltons is not really a physics unit. Try eV

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KATRIN#Experiment mentions some of the relevant issues, and it has this excellent graph of the tritium beta decay spectrum: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/KATRIN_Spectrum.svg

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you for the link and info.  That makes quite a bit more sense than the phys.org writeup.  Believe case is: If( neutrino = zero mass ) then { neutrino energy >= zero, electron curve <= 18.6 keV } else { neutrino energy >= m c ², electron curve <= 18.6 keV - m c ² and curve shape should change }

Comment: @G.Putnam Yes, that's correct. The total energy released by the decay is constant (just under 18.6 keV + the ~511 keV rest energy of the electron). The KATRIN results constrain the mass of the (anti)neutrino to <0.8 eV/c^2, so over most of the curve the KE of the neutrino is much larger than its rest energy.

Comment: An additional complication is that due to conservation of momentum the He-3 also acquires some KE (~3.4 eV in the rest frame of the tritium), but I'm not quite sure how that impacts these experiments.